# React Native: Can i add items into flatlist that is in another screen,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

problem is like this can i put this {route} into flatlist , so that in Homescreen i will send routes , they will be added in flatlist here in Details Screen? So i can see that i added my prev ones?

```
function DetailsScreen( { route } ) {
return (
    
<View>
    
      <Text> Hello this is Details  Screen + {route.params.text }</Text>
      <Text> Hello this is Details  Screen + {route.params.num}</Text>
</View>
```

this is my homeScreen:

```
     <TextInput style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="   Продукт"
          placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)}/>
  <Button
        title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', { text: text, num: num })}

      />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use react native async storage for that set param to asnyc storage using set method and get those seted param in useEffect as initial data and map them to your states.

for more details following link,
https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Comment: what if i want it just for the some time (Temporarily) ? is it possible with useState?

Comment: yeah it's temporary when u clear phone data that asnyc storage will clear

Comment: can you please show me how to put { route } as a usestate and put it to flatlist?

Comment: like following you can set your route params to varibale,                                      
const ScreenName = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const { mobileNo } = route.params; }